# Dynamically serving images from Google App engine

Tags: image, google-app-engine, blob

having problems serving an image stored as a blob from google app engine - I'm trying to view a stored image with the following code

my datastore model is:

```
class QuestionTemp(db.Model):
     picture = db.BlobProperty()
```

my post call from the initial form is:

```
class QuestionAsker3(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
      upload_files = self.request.get('file')  # 'file' is file upload
      tempQuestion = QuestionTemp(picture= db.Blob(upload_files))
      tempQuestion.put()
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/jpeg"
      self.response.out.write(tempQuestion.picture)
```

The image *is* stored in the blobstore as I can view it in the GAE admin console
"blob viewer".
In chrome the return screen in blank - firefox I get a url and what looks to be a hashcode.
many thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you are trying to view the response directly. Are you passing the response to the img tag. <img src="url" />

Comment: There is no reason that an image can't be returned. In fact, that's exactly what should happen when the server is fulfilling a request that the browser makes when dealing with an `img` tag.

Answer (score 1):

managed to solve the problem - was reading the data into the Blobstore, rather than as a Blob
so the Blob was just storing a references hence had no image data. The .value thing didn't work for me.
Thanks for helping me figure it out @abdul and @adam